# Meaning of "Black Swan"

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

Is "Black Swan" considered as an insult depend on the context it has been used ? For a instance, using "Black Swan" as a name for a company name ?

Comment: It has a rather convoluted history. First, it was used in England as a metaphor for any nonexistent thing. Then Cook found some in Austrailia? and brought them back to England, which made for good sport for a while, but changed the meaning of the metaphor. Recently, author Nassim Taleb has largely redefined the metaphor, or at least refined it. And then their was the movie that won an Oscar. Black Swan isn't an insult, but it is certainly evokes different things in different people.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory

Comment: There is a Western Australian beer company called Swan Brewery. It was named after the black swans of the area, and it has a black swan as its logo.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase goes back as far as the Roman poet [Juvenal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juvenal) who, in the late 1st or early 2nd century, [wrote](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/juvenal_satires_06.htm):

> let her be handsome, charming, rich and fertile; let her have ancient ancestors ranged about her halls; let her be more chaste than the disheveled Sabine maidens who stopped the war--a prodigy as rare upon the earth as a black swan!

"Black swan" at the time was probably a metaphor that something did not exist, but could; there is nothing theoretically impossible about such a swan, but by accident of fate, all swans are white.

When the island of Australia was first visited by Westerners, though, a large population of black swans (*Cygnus atratus*) was discovered, utterly undermining the metaphor.

About 10 years ago, the essayist Nassim Nicholas Taleb repurposed the phrase to mean something very rare, so much so that people have difficulty reasoning about it rationally.

I cannot think why it would be an insult, and there is even a book imprint, Black Swan Books, belonging to Transworld Publishers, which also puts out Bantam Books and Doubleday.